# How does the page size affected on internal fragmentation?

Tags: operating-system

In operating system internals and design principles (7th edition), there is a sentence **"the smaller the page size the lesser the amount of internal fragmentation"**. I don't understand what does it mean. As I already known, page size is equal as frame size. So, there is no internal fragmentation. I don't understand clearly what does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say your process has 12 bytes of executable code, 34 bytes of read only data and 56 bytes of read/write data. Note that each of these areas have different access permissions, and therefore (for most CPUs where permissions are associated with pages) they can't share pages.

If the page size is 100 bytes then the 12 bytes of executable code is going to have to consume 100 bytes (a whole page) and 88 bytes of that will be wasted (internal fragmentation); and the whole process will waste 198 bytes due to internal fragmentation (because the size of each of the 3 areas will need to be rounding up to the page size). If the page size is 16384 bytes then the same process would waste 49050 bytes; and if the page size was 10 bytes it'd waste 18 bytes.

More specifically; if N processes have M unique areas (where a unique area may be shared by multiple processes) you'd expect/assume that the average amount of bytes wasted due to internal fragmentation will be "M * PAGE_SIZE/2".

Comment: How did you come up with this magic number `M * PAGE_SIZE/2` ?

Comment: @Tony: If there's M unique areas, then the last page in each of the M areas will waste 0 to PAGE_SIZE bytes (which is an average of "PAGE_SIZE/2" bytes)